# XSLT test with different path levels

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Im new to XSLT and my question is if it is possible to test logically with "or" in different levels of the path or do i have to separate it somehow?

Example xml:

```
<LandXML>
    <HexagonLandXML>
        <Point lineworkFlag="START LINJE">
            <PointCode codeLinework="open line">
            </PointCode>
        </Point>
    </HexagonLandXML>
</LandXML>
```

And the example xls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:landxml="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" 
  xmlns:hexagon="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" 
              version="1.0" 
              encoding="UTF-16" 
              indent="no" 
              omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="XML" select="/"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
      <xsl:for-each select="landxml:LandXML/hexagon:HexagonLandXML/hexagon:Point">
        <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:PointCode">
          <xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]
                          /hexagon:PointCode[@codeLinework='none'] 
                          or 
                          ../../following-sibling::*[1]
                          /hexagon:Point[@lineworkFlag='START LINJE']">
            do something...
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Avoid using `for-each` at all costs and use `xsl:template match=""`

Comment: This question is unclear. Post a meaningful sample of your XML (including all namespces) and explain what you want to achieve and in which part of your current code you hit a problem. [Don't preempt the solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I agree that the question is not clear. Especially since both your expressions point to the **same** level - which is not likely to work if PointCode is a child of Point. In general, there is no reason why two expressions pointing to two completely different nodes could not be combined using OR. Each expression will be evaluated independently,

Comment: P.S. There is absolutely no reason to avoid using `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Ok maybe my edit clarifies somewhat. What I want to do is is pretty mucj straight what you can see in the code. I want to test two attributes in different levels but in the following-sibling. There are in other words several "Point" nodes with one "PointCode" node in each. I must say that I have difficulties understanding xPath even though i have read quite alot about it.

Comment: It is still unclear _why_ you would need to do that. Please also show the output you expect from the transformation. Perhaps OR'ing the conditions is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Since you don't mention the text of any error message, I guess that you aren't getting any error.  Since you nevertheless ask whether you can do what your code is doing, I guess that you aren't getting the results you want or expect.  And since I'm not completely sure what you mean by "test logically with 'or' in different levels of the path" or by "separate it somehow", I must guess a bit at your meaning.  (This is a lot of guesswork; if any of my guesses are wrong, this answer won't help much.)

I think the question you want to ask initially may b something like this:  is it legal to write a `test` attribute whose top-level operator is an `or`, when the two operands of the `or` are tests on two entirely different elements?  Or must one limit the tests in a single `test` attribute so that they don't roam all over the input?  Or, putting it another way, is this legal?

```
<xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]
                /hexagon:PointCode[@codeLinework='none'] 
                or 
                ../../following-sibling::*[1]
                /hexagon:Point[@lineworkFlag='START LINJE']">
  do something...
</xsl:when>
```

or must it be rewritten as

```
<xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]
                /hexagon:PointCode[@codeLinework='none'] ">
  do something...
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:when test="../../following-sibling::*[1]
                /hexagon:Point[@lineworkFlag='START LINJE']">
  do the exact same something...
</xsl:when>
```

The answer to that question (or: those questions) is:  yes, a `test` may have an `or` as its top-level operator; no, the two operands of the `or` need not be related, or address elements which are close to each other by any defineable proximity measure.  The first form (one `xsl:when`) is fine, and to be preferred to the second (two `xsl:when` elements) whenever the 'do something' is at all complicated.

If my guesses above are right, the news that your code is legal will eliminate one possible explanation for whatever problem you are trying to solve, but leave open the question "Then why am I not getting the output I expect?"  Since you haven't provided sample input in which this crucial bit of code will ever fire, or illustrated the desired output and the output you're currently getting, it's impossible for anyone here to answer that unasked question.

At the moment, it's clear that you're essentially writing procedural code with angle brackets in it; you may find that XSLT becomes easier to use if you work to acquire a more declarative style (by which most people including me seem to mean, among other things, using the implicit looping provided by `xsl:apply-templates` in preference to `xsl:for-each`, and using match patterns on the templates in preference to choose/when).  Or you may not; not everyone does.

As an illustration, here is a rewriting of your stylesheet in a different style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:landxml="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" 
  xmlns:hexagon="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" 
              version="1.0" 
              encoding="UTF-16" 
              indent="no" 
              omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="hexagon:Point
                         [following-sibling::*[1]
                          /hexagon:PointCode
                          /@codeLinework = 'none']
                       /hexagon:PointCode">
    <xsl:call-template name="do-something"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--* pattern on following template seems likely wrong *-->
  <xsl:template match="hexagon:HexagonLandXML
                         [following-sibling::*[1]
                          /hexagon:Point
                          /@lineworkFlag = 'START LINJE']                          
                       //hexagon:PointCode">
    <xsl:call-template name="do-something"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="do-something">
    do something ...
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your input is as regular as your example of it suggests, then your condition boils down to "either the next following PointCode element has @codeLinework='none' or the next following Point element has @lineworkFlag='START LINJE'.  If that's so, then the conditions can be shortened somewhat:

```
  <xsl:template match="hexagon:PointCode
                         [following::hexagon:PointCode[1]
                          /@codeLinework = 'none'
                          or
                          following::hexagon:Point[1]
                          @lineworkFlag='START LINJE']">
     do something...
  </xsl:template>
```

The complexity of the condition may suggest to some readers (it does to me) that the design of the XML might usefully be changed to allow more straightforward processing.  But that goes beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you. You assumed right and pointed me in the right direction even though I was unclear. The XML would use some kind of rework but im not in control of the xml.